# Kivy TextInput: TypeError: on_enter() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I have the following code (almost directly copied from https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html):

```
   18 def on_enter(instance, value):
   19     print('User pressed enter in', value)
          ...
   83 class UserInterface(BoxLayout):
   84     def __init__(self, SomeStringList, **kwargs):
   85         super(UserInterface, self).__init__(**kwargs)
              ...
   152    def callback(self, instance):
              ...
   205        textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world', multiline=False)
   206        textinput.bind(on_text_validate=on_enter)
```

When I run this I get the following error

```
   TypeError: on_enter() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

The on_text_validate does not return two arguments but one object. You can access the text using the following code:

```
18 def on_enter(instance):
19     print('User pressed enter in', instance.text)
```

You can also print more

```
18 def on_enter(instance):
19     print('User pressed enter in', instance.text, instance.id, instance.tab_width) 
          ...
205        textinput = TextInput(id="myID", text='Hello world', multiline=False)
206        textinput.bind(on_text_validate=on_enter)
```

This will print the following:

> ('The widget', 'have:', u'< InputText >', myID, 4)

See more properties at https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html